# should I use multiprocessing in all function call from the start function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I don't know if I express my intentions clear in title.You are welcome to improve it.
let's see the example:
I want the user of my site A can do some action to change some data in site B.
So I simulate login and two actions in site B .
It means I should make 3 post when a user login my site by site A account.
I have three function:

```
def login(name,pwd):
    ....
    token = get_token(name,pwd)
    set_config(token)
    open_something(token)
    ....

def set_config(toekn):
    ....

def open_something(toekn):
    ....
```

I know threading moudle,but I must build a class to use it ,which seems a bit inconvenient and graceless.
And I know mutex, like below, but it seems effectively only have one thread running at a time.

```
def login(name,pwd):
    mutex.acquire()
    try:
        print('Do some stuff')
    finally:
        mutex.release()
```

So I think I must use multiprocessing.
I want to know whether it would work if I just use below code.Or how I should write the code?

```
def login(name,pwd):
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=login, args=(name,pwd))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: I don't understand, why do you think you need to do the login in a separate process? As for what you're considering, I think it should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Blckknght yeah,but the result is not as my expect.

Comment: You need to tell us about both your expectations and what is happening instead then. We're not about to read your mind and guess what is going on.

Comment: @Blckknght I am really too careless.After checking my code again,I find the problem - my proxy service just run one thread with a resource lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=login, args=(name,pwd))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

should work. But it is as good as

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Thread(target=login, args=(name,pwd))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

which is as good as

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    login(name, pwd)
```

Comment: Yes,you are right.After checking my code again,I find the problem - my proxy service just run one thread with a resource lock.